# Display an image over another image at a particular co-ordinates in openCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, aruco

I am trying to display an image over another image at a particular co-ordinates. I have detected the aruco markers using the webcam and I want to display another image over the aruco marker. The aruco marker can be moved and the overlaying image should move along with the marker.

There is various draw functions and to input text into the image. I have tried image overlay and image homography.

I can obtain the co-ordinates for the corners.
Is there any function to insert the image at those co-ordinates?

````
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco
import glob

markerLength = 0.25

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

objpoints = [] 
imgpoints = []

images = glob.glob('calib_images/*.jpg')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)

    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners2,ret)


ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

calibrationFile = "calibrationFileName.xml"
calibrationParams = cv2.FileStorage(calibrationFile, cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ) 
camera_matrix = calibrationParams.getNode("cameraMatrix").mat() 
dist_coeffs = calibrationParams.getNode("distCoeffs").mat() 

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
    arucoParameters =  aruco.DetectorParameters_create()

    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters=arucoParameters)
    if np.all(ids != None):
        rvec, tvec, _ = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, mtx, dist) 
        axis = aruco.drawAxis(frame, mtx, dist, rvec, tvec, 0.3) 
        print(ids)
        display = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(axis, corners)
        display = np.array(display)
    else:
        display = frame

    cv2.imshow('Display',display)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```
````

Comment: It can be done simply by creating a numpy slice of target image `image[top:bottom,left:right,:]` and replacing it with source. Unless there is transparency, in which case it's a bit trickier, but can still be done with numpy. Or is it that you need to transform an image firast before inserting it (non-rectangular area) ?

Comment: Since the image is recorded from the video frame by frame, the perspective of the markers change for each frame. Hence, it is not a rectangular area

Comment: I see you found cv2.warpPerspective already, but you can make it even better if you pass the destination image to it right away. Then it will paint transformed image over it. (dst tag or 4th parameter)See documentation here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I found that image homography can be used to do it.
Here is the updated code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
    arucoParameters =  aruco.DetectorParameters_create()

    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters=arucoParameters)
    if np.all(ids != None):
        display = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners)
        x1 = (corners[0][0][0][0], corners[0][0][0][1]) 
        x2 = (corners[0][0][1][0], corners[0][0][1][1]) 
        x3 = (corners[0][0][2][0], corners[0][0][2][1]) 
        x4 = (corners[0][0][3][0], corners[0][0][3][1])  

        im_dst = frame 
        im_src = cv2.imread("mask.jpg")
        size = im_src.shape
        pts_dst = np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4])
        pts_src = np.array(
                       [
                        [0,0],
                        [size[1] - 1, 0],
                        [size[1] - 1, size[0] -1],
                        [0, size[0] - 1 ]
                        ],dtype=float
                       );


        h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
        temp = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0])) 
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(im_dst, pts_dst.astype(int), 0, 16);
        im_dst = im_dst + temp  
        cv2.imshow('Display',im_dst) 
    else:
        display = frame
        cv2.imshow('Display',display)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 9):

To replace a part of image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('Desert.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('Penguins.jpg')

img3 = img1.copy()
# replace values at coordinates (100, 100) to (399, 399) of img3 with region of img2
img3[100:400,100:400,:] = img2[100:400,100:400,:]
cv2.imshow('Result1', img3)
```

[image]

To alpha blend two images

```
alpha = 0.5
img3 = np.uint8(img1*alpha + img2*(1-alpha))
cv2.imshow('Result2', img3)
```

[image]

Comment: This is useful only for static images and rectangular area.

Comment: then create a mask for your required area in first and 2nd image then multiply the respective images with masks and add them

Answer (score 3):

@user8190410's answer works fine. Just to give a complete answer, in order to alpha blend two images with different size at a particular position, you can do the following:

```
alpha= 0.7
img1_mod = img1.copy()
img1_mod[:pos_x,:pos_y,:] = img1[:pos_x,:pos_y,:]*alpha + img2*(1-alpha)
cv2.imshow('Image1Mod', img1_mod)
```