# How can I paste an image to another image by comparing its coordinate values using PIL or opencv in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to merge two images with respect to its coordinate values.

I have done merging using single point to point merge using [Paste an image to another image at two given co-ordinates with altered opacity using PIL or OpenCV in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236363/paste-an-image-to-another-image-at-two-given-co-ordinates-with-altered-opacity-u)

I got output for that.
But I need to do multiple coordinate comparison and  merge in same 2 images..
Is there any possible way to do that?

[image: Input1]

[image: Input 2]

[image: Result]

Above images are the results. Output has only single point to point merge. But I need in multiple point merge.

The parameters are {"Headpts": [354,64, "ShoulderSpinepts": [25,234], "LeftShoulderpts": [123,243], "LeftElbowpts": [54,234], "LeftHandpts": [0, 0], "RightShoulderpts": [0, 0], "RightElbowpts": [0, 0], "RightHandpts": [0, 0], "MidSpinepts": [0, 0], "BaseSpinepts": [0, 0], "LeftHippts": [0, 0], "LeftKneepts": [0, 0], "LeftFootpts": [0, 0], "RightHippts": [0, 0], "RightKneepts": [0, 0], "RightFootpts": [0, 0], "LeftWristpts": [0, 0], "RightWristpts": [0, 0], "Neckpts": [0, 0]}

Comment: Do want to reshape the shape of  T-shirt to the person according to those point?

Comment: yes @CodingPeter my guess is if both inputs left shoulder points and right shoulder points get merge,the image will shrink according to that. Or is there any other method?

Comment: I'm trying cv2.getPerspectiveTransform. Not sure whether it works.

Comment: Can you give me all your parameter of the pictures?

Comment: @CodingPeter i edited my question with parameters. Please take a look

Comment: @CodingPeter u suggested cv2.getPerspectiveTransform. I checked  with live video. But i didnot got what i thought. If you have any examples could you please upload?

Comment: Wait a second, I'm writing the answer~

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `cv2.getAffineTransform()`. Because it can only add three point (only four on `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()`), so I cut the image to multiple triangle.

This is my sample:

[image] The point:[image]

And my goal is to reshape the cat's head in to a 300*300 box.

First, crop the **area into triangle** according the point.

[image]

And then using`cv2.getAffineTransform()` to get those specific area which had been adjusted.
[image] [image] [image]

Then use `cv2.bitwise_or()` to add them together. Generated image:
[image]

Your project is more complex, but it's the same theory. You need crop the image into **several triangle** . And then **transform them** to fit the model. After **merge those triangle together**, you can get your image.

Comment: How did u adjust the cut triangle section? You mentioned like "to get those specific area which had been adjusted."

Comment: cv2.getAffineTransform() Sample code:
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html

Comment: For static image your method is working. But when i apply it in live video, the frames are shrinking. Any other suggestions? THanks @CodingPeter

Comment: Do you know what part of your program spend most of the time? Then duel with it.